# CSS menu IE7 issue

Tags: html, css

Menu works in all major browsers but it's looking different in IE7. See screen shots below.
Check demo at http://jsfiddle.net/FQLdm/6/

When you hover your mouse over the home link, you will see a submenu. In IE7, both the menu button and submenu are pushed up.

This happened when i **replaced this**

```
.menu1 ul.menu li{
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

**with this** (I need to use this way `inline-block` to center the list items)

```
.menu1 ul.menu li{
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /*IE7*/
    *zoom:1; /*IE7*/
}
```

In Chrome it looks fine
[image: In chrome it works fine]

In IE7 it looks different. Note how the home button is raised up. it should look like the chrome screenshot above.

[image: In IE7 it looks different]

Comment: It's most likely some kind of margin issue. Do you have a reset css script? I can't be 100% for sure, but it seems like the submenu is "pushing up" the main menu item, which like i said before is most likely some kind of margin issue.

Comment: @matt I already have a CSS reset. it's not the issue. This only happened when i used `inline-block` instead of `block`. Read above

Comment: ohhh i completely missed that :p, it's because IE7 doesn't really support inline-block. It's only from IE8+. Maybe use float:left with a margin-left?

Comment: @matt I already have the hacks for IE7. read my question completely. I need to use `inline-block` so i can center the list items inside the UL.

Comment: your code is work in IE7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `vertical-align:middle` in your `li`. Like this:

```
.menu1 ul.menu li{
  vertical-align:middle;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /*IE7*/
    *zoom:1; /*IE7*/

}
```

Comment: That's perfect. vertical-align was indeed the problem. it works. Thanksss

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Example  works fine on IE7 on my PC.

Comment: May be it's a comment instead of answer :)

Comment: so write it as a comment in comment box instead of answers

Comment: in comment box i can't put a picture

Comment: I tried it out on friends pc and i still see the same issue. Try out this link and let me know what you see http://eprogramers.com/menu.html

Comment: This is the same example. I just minimized it in jsfiddle for readability, but it's still the same example

Comment: I see what you mean, there's an extra sub menu in the link i provided. I guesss this is what is causing the problem. But what exactly is causing this behavior in ie7

Comment: http://specialschool14.am/example.html this is a my example
http://specialschool14.am/example.rar you can download it

Comment: The IE conditional you have in your file doesn't work with this http://jsfiddle.net/FQLdm/6 . try it out. This is the correct jsfiddle file that you should test. it will not work in IE7

Comment: You can also download the file here to test it locally http://eprogramers.com/menu.zip

Comment: Thanks for the efforts +1. sandeep got it right. adding `vertical-align:middle` solved the problem. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

put it in yore html file in head

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
  <style>
    .menu1 ul li ul {
        position:absolute;
        top: 5px or 10px;
     }
     .menu1 {
       position: relative;
     }
  </style>        
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yes i noticed that. Don't try it on jsfiddle. They seem to execute this on a standard browser internally. just copy and paste the css and html locally and try it

Comment: Are you sure you are using IE7. I'm tried this on both desktop and laptop and i see the problem on both.

Answer (score 0):

Consult this answer: [IE6 extra padding on bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361775/ie6-extra-padding-on-bottom)

Also, not setting `display:block` can sometimes cause padding issues, as it did for me once. Try adding that to the CSS to see if anything improves.