# CSS Links Float IE7 or less

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Following CSS - works fine in IE8 or greate but not for IE7 or less:

```
  #main_navi {
   list-style:none;
   text-align:left;
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px 0px 20px 0px; 
   float:left;
  }

.dsn li {
  display: none;
}

a.main_navi_0 ul {
  float:left;
  display:none;
}

a.main_navi_0:link, a.main_navi_0:visited {
  color:blue;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:200;
  font-family: 'Allerta', sans-serif;
  height:65px;
  padding:40px 10px 0 20px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;   
}


a.main_navi_1:link, a.main_navi_1:visited {
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:200;
  font-family: 'Allerta', sans-serif;
  height:65px;
  padding:40px 10px 0 20px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;  
 color: #3c94e2;
}

a.main_navi_0:hover, a.main_navi_1:hover {
  color:#000;
  border-bottom:5px solid #3c94e2;
}    

a.sub_navi_0:link, a.sub_navi_0:visited {
  color:#696969;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:200;
  font-family: 'Allerta', sans-serif;
  height:25px;
  padding:5px 10px 0 10px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:999;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom:2px solid #dedad6;    
}

a.sub_navi_1:link, a.sub_navi_1:visited {
  color:#696969;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight:200;
  font-family: 'Allerta', sans-serif;
  height:25px;
  padding:5px 10px 0 10px;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  z-index:999;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom:2px solid #3c94e2; 
}

a.sub_navi_0:hover,  a.sub_navi_1:hover {
  color:#000;
  border-bottom:2px solid #3c94e2;
}
```

MY html-file:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="logo">
        <a target="_self" href="fileadmin/../home.html">
        <img border="0" title="4fleet Group" alt="" src="fileadmin/../fileadmin/img/logo.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
<div id="main_navi">
    <ul>
        <li class="dsn">
            <a class="main_navi_0" href="xyz.html">Über uns</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="sub_navi_0" href="xyz/team.html">Team</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="sub_navi_0" href="xyz/presse.html">Presse</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        *another li with class ="dsn" tree*
    </ul>
</div>
```

My output in IE7 or less than IE7:

```
Link1
      Link2
           Link3
```

I want it that way:

```
Link1 Link2 Link3
```

How do I get it to work in IE7. I do have an extra CSS file for IE7. I just don't know the code in CSS.

Comment: `float:inline-block;` is not valid. Whatever it is you're trying to do with that line, it won't be working in *any* browser with that code. If it is working anyway, then it means that line is probably not needed.

Comment: This I have corrected. And it is still not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS menu IE7 issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642423/css-menu-ie7-issue)

Answer (score 2):

`inline-block;` is not a valid value for `float`

I guess you meant `display: inline-block;`. This won't work in IE7 though.

What you probably want is `float: left;` but it's hard to say without seeing any HTML.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But this is not the solution. Any idea again? Would be great?

Comment: Have you tried changing your code as I mentioned above? Without your HTML we can only guess at a solution

Comment: Sorry, here is the html file.